# Plotting 'Formal class SpatialGrid' in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-sp

I want to plot a `Formal class SpatialGrid` using `ggplot2`.

I can create a grid using the following code that can be plotted in base R or `spplot`, but I want to plot in ggplot.

The following code is borrowed from [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/210092/plotting-square-grids-on-a-map-and-extracting-each-grid-information-using-r)

```
# Load libraries
library(sp)
library(raster)

# Projection
wgs.84 <- CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0")

# Load data
x <- c(76.82973, 76.82972, 76.82969, 76.83076, 76.83075, 76.83071, 76.83129, 76.83126, 76.83125) 
y <- c(28.26734, 28.26644, 28.26508, 28.26778, 28.26733, 28.26507, 28.26912, 28.26732, 28.26687) 
z <- c(-56.7879, -58.22462, -58.4211, -55.75333, -58.55153, -56.38619, -56.11011, -58.17415, -59.77212)

# Create data frame
dataset <- data.frame("LONGITUDE" = x, "LATITUDE" = y, "VALUES" = z)

# Create SpatialPointsDataFrame object  
datasetSP <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(coords = dataset[,c(1,2)], data = data.frame("id" = 1:nrow(dataset), "values" = dataset$VALUES), proj4string = wgs.84)

# Extent
extentDatasetSP <-extent(datasetSP)

# Make grid options

# Cell size (map units)
xCellSizeGrid <- 0.003
yCellSizeGrid <- 0.003

# Grid
grid <- GridTopology(cellcentre.offset = c(extentDatasetSP@xmin, extentDatasetSP@ymin),
                     cellsize = c(xCellSizeGrid, yCellSizeGrid), 
                     cells.dim = c(15, 15))


# Plot grid and points
plot(datasetSP, xlab = "Longitude", ylab = "Latitude", pch = 19)
plot(SpatialGrid(grid = grid), add = TRUE)
box()
```

**This code does work and it does allow me to subset my data using a defined grid**

But I simply want to be able to plot the grid (and the points) in ggplot2.

I have looked all over but most solutions offer a plot in base R or another plotting package.

Cheers!